# Can I call appendChild on any HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anybody know if I can call appendChild on any HTML element ?

Specifically I need to do it on input type='text' and it seems to work ? but is this correct ?

Below a snippet of my code:

```
var txt = document.createElement('input');
txt.type = 'text';
...
var div = document.createElement('div');
...
txt.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: ***Why*** do you need to do it for `<input>` element?

Comment: you can only append elements to elements that can hold elements so an input field would not work as parent

Comment: I need to add it to input because it's passed to me as input in a function. I can't call parent because it might not have one.

Comment: You only can appendChild to html layout elements. Those wich have distinct opening and closing tags. Like `span, div, a, body, head, table, tr, th, td...` But you can change all attributes of all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the w3.org on input element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) :

> Content model: Empty.

It's invalid to put an element inside an `input`.

If you want to set the value of the input, use the `value` property :

```
input.value = 'someText';
```

If what you want is to add an element before your input, use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) :

```
input.parentNode.insertBefore(div, input);
```

To insert the div after your input, you would do

```
input.parentNode.insertBefore(div, input.nextSibling);
```

Comment: thanks for that. you are probably right and I will mark this as the right answer. For the record input.parentNode assumes that the input text has a parent which might not at the time I wanted to add the div in my example... that's precisely why I asked the question

Comment: If your input element is appended to the dom, it has a parent. If you want to add a successor, your need the parent anyway.

Comment: my input element might not be appended to the dom yet

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know if I can call appendChild on any HTML element ?

You can. It is a standard feature of an element node. It might not always make sense though.

> Specifically I need to do it on input type='text' and it seems to work ? but is this correct ?

`<input>` elements are defined as empty. They still have standard DOM methods on them, but they aren't allowed to have child nodes. You are attempting to put the DOM into an invalid state, and (as far as I know) the behaviour for what happens when you do is undefined. You should not do this.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot append a child to an input element. It is a standalone element. You can however append an input element to a div element.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot append a child to an input, This is because the standard states that this element has the content model as Empty.

it only has properties that can be accessed by the "." syntax like

```
input.propertie
```